List all the macro usages in a Rust file using syn
What I want to achieve
For a given Rust file, prints all its macro invocations.
My current solution
The syn crate provides a Visit trait that can be used as a hook when traversing the AST:
struct MyCustomVisitor;

impl<'ast> syn::visit::Visitor<'ast> for MyCustomVisitor {
    fn visit_macro(&mut self, i: &'ast syn::Macro) {
         println!("{:?}", i);
         syn::visit::visit_macro(self, i);
    }
}

We can implement a custom visitor that prints the macros it encounters.
The issue of my solution
From my observation, my solution only works with the outermost macro invocations, e.g.
My solution works with the following code:
macro!()

However, for nested macro invocations,
println!("{}", macro!());

looks like my solution won't work.
Possible cause of the above behavior
syn::visit::visit_macro() skips!() the macro's tokens
I would like to know, how can I keep visit()ing the macros in the tokens. If this wouldn't let me print all the macro invocations, then how to do it, thanks!

You don't in general know what the tokens passed to a rust macro mean. Therefore without knowing what println! is and how it works you don't know macro!() within it is a macro call or just some bit that has special meaning when passed to println!. So it's not possible to count all macro invocations, without expanding all macros and counting on expansion time.

As @cafce25 said, this is impossible to do accurately (but an approximation may be good enough for you). The term you are looking for is "eager expansion".

Also note that counting expansions won't be the natural number of macros: a macro can have many internal steps, each will be its own expansion. Maybe some sophisticated span analysis is possible, but that is definitely out of scope for the proc macro API.

Hi @cafce25 and @Chayim Friedman, thanks both for the reply!
To @cafce25's reply, I think you are right, token macro!() within println!() can be a macro call, or some special syntax that is only meaningful to println!(). I wonder can we make it if we consider all the code literals like macro!()/macro![]/macro!{} as macro calls blindly?
To @Chayim Friedman's reply, yeah, you are right, a macro after expansion, can contain many macro calls, what if we don't consider the expansion thing, just rust code string literal, can we do it with this condition?
